# PHP Yii: how to row numbering CGridView if using sqlite database

Tags: php, sqlite, yii

I want to show a filter-able and sort-able column of row number in CGridView, but what i have got is only an empty sort-able (clickable header) and filter-able (it has filtering text box up there) column.

In model (ActiveRecord) class i have added a new public attribute:

```php
public $number;
```

in the rules() function i have added:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...
        ...
        array('
            ...
            ...
            number,
            ',
            'safe',
            'on'=>'search'
        ),
    );
}
```

on the search() function, i have also add:

```php
public function search()
{
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
...
...
$number_select = '( 
    select count(*)
    from tbl_mytable as k
    where k.id <= t.id
    )';
$criteria->select = array(
    $number_select . ' as number',
    't.*',
    );
...
...
$criteria->compare($number_select, $this->number,true);
$sort = new CSort;
$sort->attributes = array(
    '*',
    ...
    ...
    'number'=>array(),
    );

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>$sort,
));
}
```

I've successfully using this kind of method to add other columns.
With the lack of skill and knowledge of sqlite query, i am suspecting the cause of this problem is the query in the `$criteria->select`.

I hope someone would help me for solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after editing my question, i edited my code a fad that miraculously turn out to be the answer.

> Just remove the table alias from the select statement

Original (not working) code:

```php
$number_select = '( 
    select count(*)
    from tbl_mytable as k
    where k.id <= t.id
    )';
```

The new (working) code after removing table alias:

```php
$number_select = '( 
    select count(*)
    from tbl_mytable
    where tbl_mytable.id <= t.id
    )';
```

While my question is about yii with sqlite database, but since this is quite standard query, i think this solution will also works for yii with mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property to [`CActiveRecord.attributeNames`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#attributeNames-detail):

```
public function attributeNames()
{
    return array_merge(parent::attributeNames(), array('number'));
}
```